# pass component’s state to mapDispatchToProps React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am really new to Reac.js/Redux.js and javascript in general. I am trying to learn a new language by actually doing it. I am trying to build a log in page. But for some reason I can’t pass my inner state to my  mapDispatchToProps. I can see the values inside the component, but I can't get them outside of my class. How do i go about passing my component's state to mapDispatchToProps. Thank you id advance!!!!

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreator} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {SignInSubmit} from '../../actions/SignIn_Action';

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    userEmail: state.userInfo.userEmail,
    userPassword: state.userInfo.userPassword,
    user: state.user,
    password: state.password
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  //console.log(this.state.loginPassword);
  //console.log(this.props.user);
  return{
    onSubmit: (event) => dispatch(SignInSubmit(this.user, this.password))
  }
}



class SignIn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {
      loginPassword: '',
      loginUser: ''
    }
    // this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
    // this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
    // //this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({loginPassword: event.target.value})
    console.log(this.state.loginPassword);
  }

  onEmailChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({loginUser: event.target.value})
     console.log(this.state.loginUser);
  }
 render(){
   return (
    <main class="pa4 black-80">
     <form class="measure center">
       <fieldset id="sign_up" class="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
          <legend class="f4 fw6 ph0 mh0">Sign In</legend>
          <div class="mt3">
            <label class="db fw6 lh-copy f6" for="email-address">Email</label>
            <input 
                class="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                type="email" 
                name="email-address"  
                id="email-address"
                onChange = {this.onEmailChange}/>
          </div>
         <div class="mv3">
            <label class="db fw6 lh-copy f6" for="password">Password</label>
            <input 
                class="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                type="password" 
                name="password"  
                id="password"
                onChange = {this.onPasswordChange}/>
          </div>
       </fieldset>
       <div class="">
          <input 
              class="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib" 
              type="submit" 
              value="Sign in"
              onChange= {this.onSubmit}/>
       </div>
     </form>
  </main>
  );
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapDispatchToProps as an object will wrap your action with dispatch automatically
and pass it in as a prop.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  signIn: SignInSubmit
}
```

then in your component..

```
onSubmit: () => {
  const { loginUser, loginPassword } = this.state;
  this.props.signIn(loginUser, loginPassword);
}

<button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Sign In</button>
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but what am I dispatching in this case, and how would I pass it to my action. export const SignInSubmit = (email, password) =>{
 type: SIGNIN_SUBMIT;
 email: email;
 password: password;
}

Comment: yeh, so `connect` takes your `mapDispatchToProps` object, wraps each value in `dispatch` and sets it in props as the key, so in your props you effectively have `props.signIn = (user, pass) => store.dispatch(SignInSubmit(user, pass))`.